# Which Join do I need to use?

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

Problem: There are 2 tables that I know I need to use.

I need to find books, magazines, flyers that have the word "sport" in the title.

```
Example Table Library1: books, magazines etc,... title
Example Table Library2: flyers, etc (THIS TABLE DOES NOT HAVE title column anywhere)
```

Psuedocode: Select books, magazines, flyers from BOTH TABLES where title like '%sport%';
I need results for anything matching "sport" and to show if it's a book, magazine or whatever.

Not sure if I need a Left Join, Join, or Outer.

What's the syntax for this?

Comment: **THIS TABLE DOES NOT HAVE title column anywhere** That will be problematic. You cant `UNION` because a `UNION` must have the same columns in every `UNION` and if in Table 2 you dont have a title, what field are you using to search for `SPORT`?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. You would use a union. Example:

```
select title, 'book' as product from books where title like '%sport%'
union all
select title, 'magazine' from magazines where title like '%sport%'
union all
select title, 'flyer' from flyers where title like '%sport%'
```